# Jquery ui compressed stylesheet

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

So I have compressed jquery ui stylesheet to save bandwidth and suddenly dialog windows started to look weird.

This is how they look when I use uncompressed stylesheet:

[image]

With compressed stylesheet:

[image]

I used this website to compress the stylesheet: https://csscompressor.net/

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: What tool are you compressing it with?

Comment: @alex I have added link to the bottom of my question.

Comment: Only difference I see is with the images; check your path is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all CSS compressors are the same. It's likely the compressor has removed important syntax/grouped styles. This is one of the **cons of using a compressor; it can break things.** Difficult to tell why exactly without examining the CSS file.

Suggestions:

- Try using a different compressor
- Pretty-fy the compressed CSS to find if anything that just doesn't look right.
- Use Firebug to determine if the required styles are set

Comment: Any CSS minifier that can break things shouldn't be used :)

Comment: Absolutely alex. Classic example is the Javascript Closure Compiler on Advanced mode. Be careful with that ;)